# Find the least positive $x$ such that the expression $a + bx$ is divisible by $n$, where $a$, $b$, $n$ are assigned

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, divisibility

I'm trying to solve this general problem(to solve the programming one).

> We have assigned variables $a$, $b$ and $n$. What is the least
> positive $x$, so that $a + bx$ is divisible by $n$?
>
> It is guaranteed that $x$ exists.

So far, I have found no relations between modulo or GCD. The main trouble are the independant variables.

Comment: It is not always possible.  Try $a=1, b=2, n=4$

Comment: @Henry fixed it, thanks. $x$ is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: is $x$ expected to be an integer? which independent variables are you referring to?

Comment: A solution $x$ exists if and only if $a$ is divisible by $\operatorname{gcd}(b,n)$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Yes, an integer. I'm referring to $a$, $b$ and $n$.

Comment: See the linked dupes for methods to solve the congruence $\, bx\equiv -a\pmod{n}\ \ $